let scope in javascript
I wanted to know if someone can explain the working of scope with respect to let keyword.
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  let intervalId;

  const handleCounter = () => {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }, 1000);
    console.log("intervalId in counter:", intervalId);
  };

  const handlePause = () => {
    console.log("intervalId:", intervalId);
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter-{counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleCounter}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={handlePause}>Pause</button>
    </div>
  );
}

This is my code above, Firstly, I click on start button which triggers handleCounter(). When I try to save the setInterval id in "intervalId" variable which is a let variable and then try to clear the interval as in handlePause(). I get "undefined" in console and the counter doesn't stops.
P.S:
I understand that if I try to save the id in a state and then try to clear the interval, that will be the fix. But, I am more interested in knowing why with let function scope, it won't work?

Consider using a ref instead? The let value will be reset on each render, which will happen every time setCounter is called.

This has nothing to do with scope.
You're overlooking the fact that you're using React here.  And as soon as you call setCounter your component will re-render.  What happens when it re-renders?  This:
let intervalId;

The variable is re-declared as a local variable for this function, and is assigned no value.  So now it's undefined.
You could treat this like a scope issue and move the variable to outside the function/component.  But since you're using React, why not use React?  Make it a state value:
const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(-1);

And update that state value:
const intId = setInterval(() => {
  setCounter((prevState) => prevState + 1);
}, 1000);
setIntervalId(intId);

